# Where to find jquery mobile layout kits - Chat and Camera Layouts

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm looking for some pre-built layouts in jQuery mobile.

Like the camera layouts for example. I would need lets say at least 5-10 layouts to cover the entire process from the engagement of the camera phone to apply the final pic(s) to a photo gallery and albums. Another set of UI layouts Im looking for is chat messages.

Think about how many unique layouts are on an iPhone? There's about 4-5 layouts for your texting on your iPhone from the list view of the people you've been texting to the thread messages inside each conversation and more. Im looking for all the source code files that come along with each layout. Since Im now using jQuery mobile to do my next set of layouts, Im looking for mobile layouts that is compatible with jQuery mobile.

Any help would be appreciated. 
John